# Non-floated div pushes floated div down a line

Tags: css

With this CSS

```
#left { background: red; float: left; width: 100px; height: 100px;}
#right { background: green; float: right; width: 100px; height: 100px;}
#center { background: blue; height: 100px; margin-left: 110px; margin-right: 110px; }
```

and this html

```
<div id='left'></div>
<div id='right'></div>
<div id='center'></div>
```

It creates a fixed column, variable column, then another fixed column.

When the order is left, right, center it works just as expected
http://jsfiddle.net/6X4fN/5/.

However, when putting left, center, right, the right div is pushed onto the next line http://jsfiddle.net/6X4fN/6/.

---

I am looking for an explanation as to why this happens. The way I am understanding it, the two floated divs are removed from the document flow then the center div is scrunched with the margins. Given this, I don't see why the order of the divs would affect this layout. Since the right div is floated, the center div should not push it to the next line.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Floated divs must appear in the flow before items that are to flow around them.

"The elements after the floating element will flow around it." http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_float.asp

Comment: Thanks for the reference, never knew that mattered.

Comment: You're welcome. I've run into that before trying to have text flow around images.